# Forcing smaller line spacing (risking that text overlaps) in XeTeX

Tags: xetex, line-spacing

I am writing some XeTeX code to display Chinese text with ruby (tone marks, translation or pronunciation) above and below the characters. If on any one line, I have ruby below, and then on the next line I have ruby above another character, the line spacing will automatically be stretched to about 2, even though I have specified 1.5 in the definitions.

Is there any way to forcefully set the line spacing, taking the risk myself that some of the Ruby text might overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in fact it does nothing to do with XeTeX or CJK. Just set `\lineskiplimit` to `-\maxdimen` to disable the effect of `\lineskip`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
\usepackage{ruby}
\renewcommand\rubysep{-0.2ex}
\begin{document}

\fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{-\maxdimen}

文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字
文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字
文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字%
\ruby{文}{wén}\ruby{字}{zì}%
文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字
文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字文字
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not able to run your example (and I don't quite understand what the -\maxdimen} means. However, a solution that works well for me is to use:

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.7}
\setlength{\lineskiplimit}{-10cm}

Like that, I can indeed decrease the line spacing to less than 2 as I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: `\maxdimen` is the maximum dimension in TeX, say, 16384pt.